# AutocompleteService and Powered by Google

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to know if I should put Powered by Google when I use AutocompleteService and not Autocomplete to built my dropdown address list when users search something! 
I know if I have google map in the same page I can omit logo in the dropdown result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is explained pretty much good in the Places API Policies document:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies

> **Logo Requirements**
>
> If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a page or view that does not also display a Google Map, you must show a "Powered by Google" logo with that data. For example, if your application displays a list of places on one tab, and a Google Map with those places on another tab, the first tab must show the "Powered by Google" logo.

So, for the AutocompleteService of Google Maps JavaScript API (that internally will call the web service endpoint) just follow this policy. If you have Google maps on the same page you can omit the logo, if you don't have the map on the same page you must add the logo.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok thanks xomena! In addition I cannot use css to adjust height for google logo because policy doesn't permit